# Sharing Sharepoint documents outside intranet

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, document-management

My company utilizes Sharepoint 2007 internally to store and share documents. Now, however, we would like to include our customers in more of the development. Therefore we want to be able to share our internal Sharepoint documents with them. Of course security is a big issue as we would not like to give our customers access to all our internal documents.

I imagine some kind of a proxy server, which would be able to provide customers with the wanted documents, though it is important that permission management is easy, transparent and fine-graned.

What solutions are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we did was create another zone for extranet by extending the application onto another IIS site (so we could listen on a different IP), enabled forms-based authentication using .NET SQL Auth on that zone/site, and then created SQL users for them to log in with. This allowed us to keep them from getting an AD account and gave us fine-grained control using Sharepoint permissions.